# Restlet Kerberos Authentication

Tags: authentication, kerberos, restlet

I've followed this tutorial to implement different authentication mechanism into my application which uses Restlet: https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/security/authentication

I would like to implement Kerberos authentication into it. I could just found that tutorial:

http://blog.distributedmatter.net/post/2008/06/09/HTTP-authentication-mechanisms-and-how-they-could-work-in-Restlet

which does not explain it.

Is there any way to implement Kerberos authentication at Restlet?